# How to access github.com using a ssh key on macos?

Tags: git, macos, ssh

Github doens't allow username/password anymore to access your repo. I was able to switch to ssh key on windows. On macos I followed this guide https://medium.com/@kiran.jasvanee/the-process-to-generate-ssh-key-and-add-it-on-github-ba7139c07daf but when entering a git commad e.g. "git pull", git asks me for username und password.

I can of course provide more information but I don't know where to start searching.

Comment: check your .git/config file. Under [remote] the url should be git@local_ssh-key-host:git_username/git_repository.git  Add a "Host ssh-key-host" record to .ssh/config with proper IdentityFile path to your ssh key and Hostname github.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the root folder of your repository, and type:

```
git remote -v
```

Make sure your URL starts with `git@github.com:...`.

If not:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```

(replace `<me>/<myrepo>` by your values)

Check also if your [default SSH key works](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection):

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

You should see an error message.